# compare enum rank in swift (exercise in Swift book)

Tags: swift, enumeration

I just start to learn programming and I am trying to work out the experiment in Swift programming book.

It asks "“Write a function that compares two Rank values by comparing their raw values.”

```
enum Rank: Int {
case Ace = 1
case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
case Jack, Queen, King
func simpleDescription() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .Ace:
        return "ace"
    case .Jack:
        return "jack"
    case .Queen:
        return "queen"
    case .King:
        return "king"
    default:
        return String(self.toRaw())
    }
}
```

I wrote the following function

```
func compare(a:Rank,b:Rank) -> Bool{
return a.toRow() > b.toRow()}
```

I knew it is wrong, because toRow() is function of the members of Rank. But I don't know what is the data type of the members of the Rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raw values are Ints. Ace = 1, Two = 2, ... King = 13. The toRaw() function called on a Rank returns this Int. Note that it is toRaw() not toRow().

Answer (score 6):

There is a typo in your code which will probably prevent it from compiling correctly. The method is `toRaw` not `toRow`.

Your larger question is, "what is the data type of members of Rank." The exercise declares Rank the following way: `enum Rank: Int` so the type is Int.

Unfortunately the wording in *The Swift Programming Language* makes it easy to overlook, but there is a subtle difference in the declaration of Enums that have members with raw values, and Enums that have associated values (or no values).

Here's the example of raw Enums from the book:

```
enum ASCIIControlCharacter: Character { // note type declaration
    case Tab = "\t"
    case LineFeed = "\n"
    case CarriageReturn = "\r"
}
```

The key is the type declaration `: Character` which follows the name of the Enum. If you try to declare it like this:

```
enum ASCIIControlCharacter { // missing type declaration
    case Tab = "\t" // won't work!
    case LineFeed = "\n"
    case CarriageReturn = "\r"
}
```

You will get `error: enum case cannot have a raw value if the enum does not have a raw type`.

So the type of the raw value for each member has to match the declared type of the Enum.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_190

Answer (score 3):

```
func compare(a: Rank , b: Rank) -> Bool {
    return a.rawValue > b.rawValue
}

compare(a:two, b: ace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this eventually:

```
func compareVals (a:Rank, b:Rank) -> String {
    var result: String
    if a.rawValue>b.rawValue {
        result = a.simpleDescription() + " is higher than " + b.simpleDescription()
    }
    else {
        result = b.simpleDescription() + " is higher than " + a.simpleDescription()
    }
    return result
}

compareVals(a:Rank.five, b:Rank.king)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.2

Page 44, Exercise

```
func compare(a: Rank, b:Rank)-> Bool{
return a.rawValue > b.rawValue
```

}

compare(a: Rank.nine, b: ace)

Comment: This is almost identical to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500367/12695027) provided by Ishaan Bajpai in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Another example with operator overloading

```
func ==(lhs: Rank, rhs: Rank) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
}

func >(lhs: Rank, rhs: Rank) -> Bool {
    return lhs.rawValue > rhs.rawValue
}

let ace = Rank.ace
let two = Rank.two

ace == two // false
two > ace // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare a

> func compare() {}

outside of the

> enum Rank: Int {}

This is the enum Rank:

```
enum Rank: Int {
  case ace = 1
  case two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
  case jack, queen, king

func simpleDescription() -> String {
  switch self {
        case .ace:
            return "ace"
        case .jack:
            return "jack"
        case .queen:
            return "queen"
        case .king:
            return "king"
        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
      }
   }
}
```

> now declare the function:

```
func compare(a: Rank, b: Rank) -> String {
  let result = a.rawValue - b.rawValue

  if result < 0 {
      return "\(b) is bigger than \(a)"
  }
  else if result > 0 {
      return "\(a) is bigger than \(b)"
  }
  else {
      return String()
  }
}
```

> now call the function:

```
compare(a: Rank.jack, b: Rank.king)
```

> Playground shows some description text like: **a** bigger than **b** or wise verse. But you can modify it as you wish.